# C# LINQ Query to project and concat two sequences of unlike entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have three tables in a db that correspond to Entities in our code. (I am dumbing these classes down for simplicity)

```
public class Current{
    [Key]
    public int CurrentId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int TableKeyId {get; set;}

    public string Value {get; set;}
}

public class Promotion{
    [Key]
    public int PromtionId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int TableKeyId {get; set;}

    public string Value {get; set;}
}

public class TableKey{
    [Key]
    public int TableKeyId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string PlanCode {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public byte Environment {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public byte FileId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string TableNumber {get;set;}

}
```

(The Current and Promotion both have TableKeyId Foreign Key properties).

What I need to do is pull from all three repositories retrieving the Currents and Promotions  getting their value and the TableKey properties. **I need all of the Promotions if they exist and the Currents where their TableKeyId does not equal any TableKeyId from the Promotions**. I tried to accomplish this with the following query:

```
var query = (from c in this.currentRepository.Query()
                     join t in this.tableKeyRepository.All() on c.TableKeyId equals t.TableKeyId
                     join p in this.promotionRepository.Query() on c.TableKeyId equals p.TableKeyId into pc
                     from p in pc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where (t.PlanCode == command.PlanCode && t.Environment == command.Environment)
                     select new Temptable
                     {
                         TableNumber = t.TableNumber,
                         PlanCode = t.PlanCode,
                         FileId = t.FileId,
                         Value = (p == null ? c.Value : p.Value),
                         TableKeyId = c.TableKeyId
                     });
```

This query **almost** works, except when a Promotion exists that has a TableKeyId that does not correspond to a Current with the same TableKeyId - it won't retrieve those because it's a left outer join. I know I could do it with multiple queries, but I really wanted one single query. Also keep in mind that each table could have around 1million records, so I have to optimize the query.

So if I had the following:

TableKeys

```
TableKeyId,PlanCode,Environment,FileId,TableNumber
--------------------------------------------------
1,"001",2,"PFT","A1234"
2,"001",2,"PFT","A1235"
3,"001",2,"PFT","A1236"
4,"001",2,"PFT","A1237"
```

Currents

```
CurrentId,TableKeyId,Value
--------------------------
1,1,"A"
2,2,"B"
3,4,"C"
```

Promotions

```
PromotionId,TableKeyId,Value
---------------------------
1,1,"G"
2,2,"H"
3,3,"I"
```

I would expect the result set if Environment was 2 and PlanCode was "001" in my query to be

```
TableKeyId,PlanCode,Environment,FileId,TableNumber,Value
--------------------------------------------------------
1,"001",2,"PFT","A1234","G"
2,"001",2,"PFT","A1235","H"
3,"001",2,"PFT","A1236","I"
4,"001",2,"PFT","A1237","C"
```

I really appreciate all feedback :)

Thank you!

Comment: @James, why delete that comment, it helped :) I did end up rewriting the query. (editing question).